# Analyzing equilibrium points using the determinant and trace of the system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose I am trying to analyse the equilibrium points of a system, and I would want to figure that out by computing three things: The determinant, the trace of the matrix, and the discriminant. Now for the determinant, I know that if $D<0$, then the eigenvalues of the supposed system must have opposite signs. So I guess this little piece of information if the points is either a saddle, nodal sink, or a nodal source. And the value of the trace here wouldn't be relevant.

Now I am only wondering when is the value of the trace more important than the determinant and I am guessing it is only in the case where the discriminant is $T^{2}-4D>0$, and we have two complex conjugate eigenvalues.

I am guessing that in the case where $T$ is positive, then the real part of these complex conjugate eigenvalues are positive, and if $T$ is negative, then the real part would also be negative. Does this seem like a correct way of analyzing equilibrium points?

I am just confused, because it seems to me that the value of the determinant is important only when the system does not have complex conjugates, and the trace is irrelevant. But in case of a complex conjugate then the determinant is irrelevant (it will only help to find the discriminant) and only $T$ matters?

Comment: This sounds like a decent way to do equilibrium analysis to me. It's a little weird to call the determinant useless when the system does not have complex conjugates because *a priori* you don't know whether the system has complex conjugates or not. The determinant gives you a way to rule out complex conjugates, and in case it fails to rule it out, then moving onto the trace is the next step. In either scenario, you extracted useful information from it.

Comment: Are you talking about the mechanics of using the Hartman-Grobman theorem, or something else? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartman%E2%80%93Grobman_theorem)